# Checking current time in php has passed SQL time

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to check the time right now is newer then a DATETIME from a SQL row. This is my current code:

```
<?php
require('common.php');

$query = "SELECT 
                 event_name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(event_date) AS event_time, initiator, min_level, max_level
              FROM 
                 DD_events
          WHERE
           event_date <= NOW()
          ";
try{
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
}
catch(PDOException $ex){
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
}
$chk = $stmt->fetchall();

//Loop through each row
foreach ($chk as $chks) {
print_r($chks['event_time']); echo "<br>";
  // If it is, create query to make the next event
    $query = "INSERT INTO
              DD_events (event_name, event_date, initiator, min_level, max_level)
              VALUES 
              (:name, :event_date, 0, :min_lvl, :max_lvl)
          ";
  $query_params = array(
                   ':name' => $chks['event_name'],
                   ':event_date' => $chks['event_time'],
                   ':min_lvl' => $chks['min_level'],
                   ':max_lvl' => $chks['max_level']
                   );
    try
    {
        // These two statements run the query against your database table.
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        // Note: On a production website, you should not output $ex->getMessage().
        // It may provide an attacker with helpful information about your code. 
        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }
}
```

The results always turn up empty even though I know that there are supposed to be turning up.

My goal is to check to see if an event has passed. If it has execute the code.

I understand that PHP time differes from SQL time and that is why I attempted the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function to try and compare it to the PHP time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to just select the rows that you need (if you are not going to use the other ones in your code):

```
$query = "SELECT 
            event_name, event_date, initiator, min_level, max_level
          FROM 
            DD_events
          WHERE event_date <= NOW()
          ";
```

That would reduce your php code and the resources needed.

Comment: I will try that. It would definitely make things easier.

Comment: It works. But now the time that gets entered is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 instead of the date that was grabbed.

Comment: @Matt What time gets entered where? You can still select the timestamp using MikeB's answer as a column in your result set if you need it.

Comment: I want the function to take the current time if it's older then the time now, make a new event 1 day later (I'm having trouble with that but that's a different subject) and then insert into the table the new date. Right now, I am just trying to get the same event to duplicate. IE: grab the details from expired events and then making the same event again. Right now, it is recognizing the expired events and making new ones, but the dates on the new ones are all `0000-00-00 00:00:00`.

Comment: @Matt That is a totally different question, you would need to post the code that changes the date for us to see where the problem could be. By the way, this you could also do in just sql.

Comment: I edited the OG post to my current coding. There will be more coding later (I need to delete data from another table and eventually delete the old event but I'm taking this one step at a time)

Comment: @Matt You need to get rid of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` if you are going to insert the same date in the same field.

Answer (score 3):

You apply the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` function in your select but you don't alias it to anything. So your result-set includes event_date and a numeric key representing the value of `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(event_date)` which you never access.

```
SELECT event_name, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(event_date) event_date, initiator, min_level, max_level FROM DD_events
#         Alias the result of the function ---^
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I make timers that rely on times from databases:

```
$timeToWait = 120; // 2 minutes
$result_set = .....;
if(time() - $result_set['time'] > $timeToWait) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `DateDiff`, `Date_Sub` functions to check if both dates results in a difference or a null or a zero.

That could define witin MYSQL Query only though.

```
SELECT event_name, 
UNIX_TIMESTAMP(event_date) MYSQLDtTime,
DateDiff(time(), UNIX_TIMESTAMP(event_date) ) as timdiff, 
initiator, 
min_level, 
max_level 
FROM DD_events;
```

So you may validate `timediff` column.